# NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I have a task that I did not build but is no longer working. i am new to ruby on rails and have not found a solution for this problem yet.

when i run the task i Get:

this is the task:

```
  desc "Archive Loads/Trucks that have expired."
  task :expire_old_posts => :environment do
    expired_loads = []
    loads = Load.where("pickup < NOW()")
    loads.each {|load| expired_loads << load.attributes } 
    ArchivedLoad.create( expired_loads )
    loads.delete_all
  end
```

**little Debugging thru console**

Confirms there are 120530 loads to transfer:

```
loads = Load.where("pickup < NOW()").count    
2014-07-23 12:55:56 DEBUG --    (149.8ms)  SELECT COUNT(*) FROM "loads" WHERE (pickup < NOW())
 => 120530
```

create the empty array:

```
expired_loads = []
=> []
```

run the where command

```
loads = Load.where("pickup < NOW()")
```

lots and lots of records... i limited it to two for testing

```
1.9.3-p547 :006 > loads = Load.where("pickup < NOW()").limit(2)
2014-07-23 13:02:07 DEBUG --   Load Load (74.2ms)  SELECT "loads".* FROM "loads" WHERE (pickup < NOW()) LIMIT 2
 => [#<Load id: 18398947, user_id: 11074, origin: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x595f056 "POINT (-80.48237609863281 37.772544860839844)">, dest: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x595ec64 "POINT (-78.30302429199219 40.295894622802734)">, length: 48, comments: "~PostEverywhere_20140721140916~", ltl: false, rate: nil, delivery: "2014-07-22 17:00:00", pickup: "2014-07-21 17:00:00", weight: 48, equipment_id: 8, covered: false, created_at: "2014-07-21 19:16:16", updated_at: "2014-07-21 19:16:16", owner: nil, deleted: false, origin_city: "ronceverte", origin_state: "wv", dest_city: "martinsburg", dest_state: "pa">, #<Load id: 18398948, user_id: 11074, origin: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x553cd2a "POINT (-81.035400390625 37.384891510009766)">, dest: #<RGeo::Geographic::SphericalPointImpl:0x553c9d8 "POINT (-79.80570983886719 40.317527770996094)">, length: 48, comments: "~PostEverywhere_20140721140916~", ltl: false, rate: nil, delivery: "2014-07-22 17:00:00", pickup: "2014-07-21 17:00:00", weight: 48, equipment_id: 8, covered: false, created_at: "2014-07-21 19:16:16", updated_at: "2014-07-21 19:16:16", owner: nil, deleted: false, origin_city: "princeton", origin_state: "wv", dest_city: "greenock", dest_state: "pa">]
```

Really not sure what the << is but i assume this is just distributing the attributes so that they can be saved in the other table

```
loads.each {|load| expired_loads << load.attributes }
```

Errors here with

```
**NoMethodError: undefined method `<<' for nil:NilClass**
```

Next line is: Saves them to archived_loads table and deletes from loads table

```
ArchivedLoad.create( expired_loads )
loads.delete_all
```

Answer (score 0):

Why not use `#map` instead? `expired_loads = loads.map(&:attributes)` or better yet just create a method in `Load` to archive them e.g.

```
class Load
  scope :expired_loads, -> {where("pickup < NOW()")}
  def self.archive_now
    ArchiveLoad.create(expired_loads.map(&:attributes))
    expired_loads.delete_all
  end        
end
```

Then you can call `Loads.archive_now` I am unsure of any of your structure this is just a suggestion as to a more concise implementation.

It also might be prudent to post the `create` method of your `ArchivedLoad` in case you have utilized the `<<` method inside of there as well. If you have not implemented some kind of a custom `create` method I think you need a iteration instead such as

```
expired_loads.map(&:attributes).each{|load| ArchiveLoad.create(load)}
```

Also `<<` is similar to `push` it adds an object to the end of an `Array`